# Spatial query w/o spatial data

Tags: oracle, spatial, spatial-index, oracle-spatial

I trying to execute a next query on Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition (11.1.0.6.0):

```
SELECT "__ItemId"
FROM "Cities"
WHERE "Longitude" IS NOT NULL AND "Latitude" IS NOT NULL
  AND SDO_ANYINTERACT(SDO_GEOMETRY('POINT(' || "Longitude" || ' ' || "Latitude" || ')'),
    SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY('POLYGON ((-100 80, 100 80, 100 -80, -100 -80, -100 80))')) = 'TRUE'
```

Where "Longitude" and "Latitude" - numeric [NUMBER(28,5)] columns in the "Cities" table.

**UPD**: Next query (with the same error) can be used for tests:

```
SELECT 'Solved!'
FROM DUAL
WHERE SDO_ANYINTERACT(SDO_GEOMETRY('POINT(' || 100 || ' ' || 100 || ')'),
  SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY('POLYGON ((-150.0 82.0, 150.0 82.0, 150.0 -67.0, -150.0 -67.0, -150.0 82.0))')) = 'TRUE';
```

I get an error:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-13226: interface not supported without a spatial index
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MD", line 1723
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MDERR", line 8
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_3GL", line 71
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_3GL", line 239
13226. 00000 -  "interface not supported without a spatial index"
  *Cause:    The geometry table does not have a spatial index.
  *Action:   Verify that the geometry table referenced in the spatial operator
             has a spatial index on it.
```

Questions:

1. How can I check, that point with specified "Longitude" and "Latitude" in the specified polygon? Polygon in not always simple, it can be any.
2. How can I create a spatial index on a table without any spatial column?
3. It's really, I can not just call a spatial operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error messages state, you need a Spatially indexed column to make use of the Spatial operators.

You can get equivalent functionality from the `RELATE` function in the `SDO_GEOM` package using the mask "ANYINTERACT":

```
SELECT sdo_geom.relate(a, 'ANYINTERACT', b, 0.05)
FROM dual
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_objgeom.htm#BGHCDIDG

Comment: Sorry, one more question: will this way use spatial indexes when they exists? When "a" or "b" is a spatial column in a table with spatial index on this column?

Comment: In my tests indexes not used (for SDO_ANYINTERACT index is used), but this is OK - question about table with out spatial index. Thanks for you answer! I will use different ways.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the documentation says that the first shape (a) could be from a spatially indexed column, but as with everything Oracle there are no guarantees of index use.

Comment: Yes, I was tried with first shape is geometry field with spatial index and TABLE ACCESS (FULL) was performed :о( When SDO_ANYINTERACT used, the index was used. In any case, thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

first, you can not create spatial index on a table without any spatial column, and sdo_anyinteract uses spatial index, there are many spatial operator in oracle you can try another one,

I'm not sure but you can try `sdo_relate(obj1,obj2,'querytype=window mask=anyintereact')`

hope it works.

Comment: Thanks! The same query with WHERE …SDO_RELATE(SDO_GEOMETRY('POINT(' || "Longitude" || ' ' || "Latitude" || ')'), SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY('POLYGON ((-100 80, 100 80, 100 -80, -100 -80, -100 80))'), querytype=window mask=anyintereact') = 'TRUE'; Generates the same error.